# Getting java.lang.nullPointerException for populating from existing database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have an existing database that I created and I would like to get the data from that to populate a listview in android. For now I would first just like to get my database connected and working and see if I can get the data out of it. My database is called HealthySizing and in it I have a Shirts table with 6 columns. So I have a DBHelper class, a MainActivity.java, and an activity_main.xml, I have posted below these three files and the error that I get, so can someone help me out with this? Does anyone know why I am getting this error and how I can fix it to get some data out of my database?

```js
package com.example.ListViewFromSQLiteDB;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Locale;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.ListViewFromSQLiteDB/databases";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "HealthySizing.db";
    private static final int SCHEMA_VERSION = 1;
    public SQLiteDatabase dbSqlite;
    private final Context myContext;
    public static String tableName = "Shirts";

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, SCHEMA_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public void createDatabase() {
        createDB();
    }

    private void createDB() {

        boolean dbExist = DBExists();

        if (!dbExist) {

            this.getReadableDatabase();
            copyDBFromResource();

        }

    }

    private boolean DBExists() {

        SQLiteDatabase db = null;

        try {

            String databasePath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(databasePath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
            db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
            db.setLockingEnabled(true);
            db.setVersion(1);

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            Log.e("SqlHelper", "database not found");
        }

        if (db != null) {
            db.close();
        }

        return db != null ? true : false;

    }

    private void copyDBFromResource() {

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        OutputStream outStream = null;
        String dbFilePath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

        try {

            inputStream = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(dbFilePath);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;

            while((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
            inputStream.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Problem copying database from resource file");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (dbSqlite != null) {
            dbSqlite.close();
        }
        super.close();
    }

}

/*public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public SQLiteDatabase DB;
    public String DBPath;
    public static String DBName = "HealthySizing";
    public static final int version = '3';
    public static Context currentContext;
    public static String tableName = "Shirts";

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBName, null, version);
        currentContext = context;
        DBPath = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases";
        createDatabase();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private void createDatabase() {

        boolean dbExists = checkDbExists();

        if (dbExists) {
            // do nothing
        }




    }

    private boolean checkDbExists() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {
            String myPath = DBPath + DBName;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {

            // database doesn't exist yet.

        }

        if (checkDB != null) {

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

}
    */
```

```css
package com.example.ListViewFromSQLiteDB;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    private String tableName = DBHelper.tableName;
    private SQLiteDatabase newDB;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        openAndQueryDatabase();
        displayResultList();

    }
    private void displayResultList() {
        TextView tView = new TextView(this);
        //tView.setText("This data is retrieved from the database and only 4 " +
        //        "of the results are displayed");
        getListView().addHeaderView(tView);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
        getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    }
    private void openAndQueryDatabase() {
        try {
            DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
            newDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

            Cursor c = newDB.rawQuery("SELECT Brand  FROM " +
                    tableName, null);

            if (c != null ) {
                if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        String brand = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Brand"));
                        results.add(brand);

                    }while (c.moveToNext());
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLiteException se ) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
        } finally {
            if (newDB != null)
                newDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + tableName);
            newDB.close();
        }

    }

}
```

```html
04-11 15:41:48.558    1923-1923/com.example.ListViewFromSQLiteDB I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
04-11 15:41:51.974    1923-1923/com.example.ListViewFromSQLiteDB E/MainActivity﹕ Could not create or Open the database
04-11 15:41:51.975    1923-1923/com.example.ListViewFromSQLiteDB D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
    --------- beginning of crash
04-11 15:41:51.975    1923-1923/com.example.ListViewFromSQLiteDB E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ListViewFromSQLiteDB, PID: 1923
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ListViewFromSQLiteDB/com.example.ListViewFromSQLiteDB.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.close()' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.close()' on a null object reference
            at com.example.ListViewFromSQLiteDB.MainActivity.openAndQueryDatabase(MainActivity.java:59)
            at com.example.ListViewFromSQLiteDB.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
device not found
```

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ListViewFromSQLiteDB"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name="com.example.ListViewFromSQLiteDB.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:layout_weight="0.12" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the finally block of openAndQueryDatabase you call newDB.close() without check if it's null. Try this:

```
} finally { 
    if (newDB != null){
        newDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + tableName); 
        newDB.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: That still didn't fix it, for some reason, I'm still getting the same error. Do you know if there's anything else we can do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
finally {
        try {
            if (newDB != null){
                newDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + tableName );
            newDB.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: That fixed the null exception error, but now I'm just getting one final error, it says that it cannot open or create the database, do you know why that could be? So my database is Called HealthySizing, it has a table called Shirts and has 6 columns and it even has that meta table in there too that you're supposed to have, but it doesn't have an id column though, so could that be the problem?